# How to convert a List of strings into a Map with Streams

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have to convert a list `List<String>` into a map `Map<String, Float>`.

The *keys* of the *map* must be strings from the *list*, and every **value** must be `0` (zero) for all *keys*.

How can I convert this?

I've tried:

```java
List<String> list = List.of("banana", "apple", "tree", "car");

Map<String, Float> map = list.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, 0f));
```

Comment: is your question resolved?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to associate every *key* with `0`, the second argument of the `toMap()` needs to be a *function* returning `0`, but not the value of `0`:

```
Map<String, Float> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),  // extracting a key
        str -> 0f,            // extracting a value
        (left, right) -> 0f   // resolving duplicates
    ));
```

Also, there's no need to use `distinct()`. Under the hood, it'll create a `LinkedHashSet` to eliminate duplicates, in case if most of the stream elements are unique and the data set is massive, it might significantly increase memory consumption.

Instead, we can deal with them within the map. For that we need to add the third argument `mergeFunction`.

And there's no need to invoke `toString()` method on a stream element which is already a string to extract a *key* of type `String`. In such cases, we can use `Function.identity()` to signify that no transformations required.

Answer (score 2):

Another way doing the the same without using `stream`.

```
Map<String,Float> map = new HashMap<String, Float>();       
list.forEach(s-> map.computeIfAbsent(s,v->0f));
```

Answer (score 1):

The below works fine,

```
Map<String, Float> collect =  
 list.stream() .collect(Collectors
     .toMap(Function.identity(),
             a -> 0f));
```